# Angular - father component is not catching event from child component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new on Angular and I am doing a course about it. In this moment I am studying how to pass values between components.

For this reason, I created two components (father and child) and what I expect is that the father catch the value emitted from child by pressing a button.

To do some tests, I put two alerts (one when emit starts - this is displayed - and another one when the emit should be received - this isn't displayed).

This is my code:

app.component.html

```
<app-figlio2 (notificaEvento)="catturaEvento($event)"></app-figlio2>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hello world';
  valoreTest = 'valore di prova';
  valoreCatturato:number = 0;
  catturaEvento(parametro: any){
    alert("cattura evento");
    //this.valoreCatturato = parametro;
  }
}
```

Here, if I set number type for variable 'parametro' I get a type error so for now I set it any type.

figlio2.component.html

```
<button (click)="notificaEvento()">Write 15</button>
```

figlio2.component.ts

```
varDaEmettere:number = 15;
@Output() notificaValore = new EventEmitter<number>();

notificaEvento(){
    alert("notifica evento "+ this.varDaEmettere);
    this.notificaValore.emit(this.varDaEmettere);
  }
```

Angular CLI: 14.2.9
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 14.2.10

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

what I expect is that the father catch the value emitted from child by pressing a button.

Comment: is there any error? as of me code is ok

Comment: or just share stackbliz link to check the issue.

Comment: do you import `EventEmitter` from '@angular/core'?  did the first alert displayed ?

Comment: try `<app-figlio2 (notificaValore)="catturaEvento($event)"></app-figlio2>` instead of `(notificaEvento)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event that you set - that can be fired is the event you declare in the child component - `notificaValore`, so this is what you need to fire.

```
<app-figlio2 (notificaValore)="catturaEvento($event)"></app-figlio2>
```

the name of the method inside child component - `notificaEvnto` is not relevant

Comment: this was the issue. Thank you